# Sed command is misbehaving when a exclamation mark is included in the regex

Tags: regex, sed

I have this task where I have to extract the usernames and the hashed passwords from /etc/shadow but I'm having a problem when replacing the stream with the sed command.

I have tried this command:

```
sed '/s/*/NoPassword/; s/!/LockedPassword/' /etc/shadow | awk -F: '{ print $1" "$2 }' > passwords.txt
```

It works fine when it comes to replacing the "!" with LockedPasswords, but some users have "!!" in the field and not "!", so I have tried other commands.

These ones give no result at all, the password fields containing either one or more question marks stay the same

```
sed '/s/*/NoPassword/; s/!+/LockedPassword/' /etc/shadow | awk -F: '{ print $1" "$2 }' > passwords.txt

sed '/s/*/NoPassword/; s/!{1,2}/LockedPassword/' /etc/shadow | awk -F: '{ print $1" "$2 }' > passwords.txt
```

What seems to be the problem? I'm only a beginner for both linux and regex.

Comment: @EdMorton There is now :-) ... you put one in your comment

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen touche. Happy to help :-)

Comment: @Hsen - you mean "exclamation mark" (`!`), not "question mark" (`?`). Also you mention "fields" - if you show us sample input/output we can improve the solution by focusing the change only on the field(s) that should be changed.

Comment: @EdMorton Sorry about that, I just fixed it and Tim solved it for me. Thank you.

Comment: No problem but for next time: any time you're piping between any combinations of sed, grep, and awk - you don't need to do that, you can just do whatever it is in one call to awk since awk can do anything useful that sed and/or grep can do.

Comment: I'm going to keep that in mind, really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both `+` and `{` `}` need to be escaped in Sed.  So both of your attempts should work after fixing this:

```
sed '/s/*/NoPassword/; s/!\+/LockedPassword/' /etc/shadow | awk -F: '{ print $1" "$2 }' > passwords.txt

sed '/s/*/NoPassword/; s/!\{1,2\}/LockedPassword/' /etc/shadow | awk -F: '{ print $1" "$2 }' > passwords.txt
```

Comment: You should mention that `\+` is a GNU-ism, it'll remain a literal `+` in other seds. `\{1,\}` is the POSIX equivalent but your `\{1,2\}` is a better, more strict match in this case.

Comment: `x\+` is a synonym for `xx*`. In GNU sed, by employing the `-r` or `-E` option the same can be expressed as `x+` or `x{1,}`.

Answer (score 3):

You never need sed when you're using awk. Your whole command line can just be:

```
awk -F':' '{sub(/\*/,"NoPassword"); sub(/!+/,"LockedPassword"); print $1, $2}' /etc/shadow > passwords.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `-E` flag:

```
sed -E '/s/*/NoPassword/; s/!+/LockedPassword/' /etc/shadow | awk -F: '{ print $1" "$2 }' > passwords.txt
```